# Working with Express and SQLite (connection and disconnection) Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite

I have a question about the integration of SQLite (but in general of the DB) with Node.js with and Express framework.

From what I know, it is always good to open and close a connection to the db. But in Node.js, the processes are asynchronous (some times).

```
router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  let db = new sqlLite.Database(path.resolve("data.db"), (err) => {
   if (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
   }
   console.log("Connected to the chinook database.");
  });
  db.get(`SELECT * FROM data WHERE key = '${req.query.data}'`, (err, row) => {
   res.json(row);
  });
  db.close((err) => {
   if (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
   }
  console.log("Close the database connection.");
 });
});
```

in this example, I open and close the connection directly within the route, so that it only handles the event in that case. Is this approach correct? what do you recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most cases, the better approach is to use some kind of connection pool, but depending on your application that may or may not matter.

That said, two things that will matter.  First, you really need to close the connection during the callback, not subsequent to the query call:

```
router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  let db = new sqlLite.Database(path.resolve("data.db"), (err) => {
   if (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
   }
   console.log("Connected to the chinook database.");
  });
  db.get(`SELECT * FROM data WHERE key = '${req.query.data}'`, (err, row) => {
   db.close((err) => {
     if (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
     }
     console.log("Close the database connection.");
   });
   res.json(row);
  });
});
```

Second, though not related to your question, is that template strings are *not* safe from SQL injection attacks.  So you really should not take direct user input from req.body or req.query or similar and concatenate it with your query, unless you're comfortable with a malicious user destroying your DB.

To avoid the injection problem, it's a good idea to both validate that the user input falls into an acceptable range of values but also use [prepared statements](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/API#databaserunsql-param--callback) to properly escape potentially malicious values.

Comment: What do you recommend to avoid sql injection?

Comment: @Eugenio updated to add that for you, sorry that I didn't the first go-round.